# Consider a real equation of $x$. Is it enough to prove $\Rightarrow$ to obtain all solutions or is both ways neccesary to verify solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Consider  a real equation of $x$. Is it enough to prove $\Rightarrow$ to obtain all solutions or is both ways neccesary to verify solutions ?

Suppose we have a simple equation in $\mathbb R$: $f(x) = f^{'}(x)$.

As an example consider $3x + 5 = 7$.

Normally I solve this equation as follows:

$3x + 5 = 7 \Rightarrow 3x = 7 - 5 \Rightarrow x = 2/3$.

I have been arguing with a freind whether it is neccesary to prove "both ways" i.e. $3x+5= 7 \iff x=2/3$ ? Or is it enough to prove one way as above ?

Proving $\Rightarrow$ imply that a solution must have the obtained form. However we need to prove $\Leftarrow$ in order to prove the obtained form(s) are actually solutions ?

Comment: You always gotta check the domain...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, consider this evil question : 
[image]

There's nothing wrong, right? Wrong.

Now if you plug your $a=-\frac{17}{2}$ in your original limit then you see that numerator is positive but the $[\text{ } ]$ term in denominator becomes negative. Hence, $a $ can't be negative.

You must plug your solution back in the original equation just in case... Also, find the solution for : 
$${\tan {2x}-\tan{x}}=1+\tan x  \tan 2x$$

Solve for $x$. Sure, that simplifies to : $\tan{2x-x}=1\implies \tan x =1\implies x= n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$

Wrong again! as $\tan{2x}$ is not defined at those values. The answer is no solution.

You have to check the domain of your original expression and all your steps must be reversible. If not, plug it back to check.

Comment: Thank you ! In the $\tan$ example do you use some trigometric identity to get $\tan2x - x = 1$ ?

Comment: @AndreasLykke yes,  tan(a-b)